# How to make a shortcut key for switching to Texture paint mode?

Tags: texture-painting, shortcut

I cant find a key shortcut to use Texture paint mode. I wonder how can I make one cause it's a pain to have to change the mode using the menu back and forth.

Comment: There are 2 Pie Menu addons shipped with Blender (in addons search type `pie`). With them all interaction modes will be accessible via Tab. Requires some practice but once you get used to it it's quite handy

Comment: Mr Zak's answer is the best option - pie menu access is consistent even with the new 2.8 interaction.

Answer (score 1):

There are no exact hotkeys for mode change. But you can assign custom keys by **left-clicking** on mode then **click add shortcut** and press key on keyboard to assign.[image]

I recommend, before adding key as shortcut, go to **user preferences->input-> change filter** to **keybinding** then press shortcut to see what are assigned to it.
[image]

There is more related info in following link:
https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-set-custom-shortcuts-for-mode-switching/626237